# Expand arrow element to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two arrows on a slider, pointing left and right. On hovering over these arrows, I want the arrows to expand to say "Prev" or "Next", depending on which one is selected.

On the left arrow, this is fine, as I set the whole div to contain the arrow image, and then the word 'PREV, and set the size of the container so that only the arrow is visible. Then on rollover, I have the width of the container increase.

However, this tactic doesn't work on the right arrow, as the arrow presents itself and then on hover the word 'NEXT' appears to the right of it, whereas I want it on the left. If I put the word before the arrow, then I only see the word and not the arrow until hovering over it.

Is there any way using CSS and/or jQuery to show only the rightmost element data, and then have the width increase to the left on hover? Ideally I want to turn this into an 'animate' function, and don't want to have to use two images - one with the arrow, and one with the arrow and text.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Dan

EDIT

Have just found out about JSFIDDLE, so have copied my code (minus the images atm) to there at http://jsfiddle.net/VzNFw/ with the modifications suggested; however I would like to get the formatting a bit better on the word displaying. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't sound too complicated, but it's hard to answer without a demonstration. If you could make one using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for that thirtydot, hadn't heard of that site before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done without CSS3 in a very similar way and should work in IE <strike>(disclaimer: although I can't test on the machine I'm using)</strike>, just tested in IE8 and it works.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <a class="left" href="">&lt;<span>Left</span></a>
    <a class="right" href=""><span>Right</span>&gt;</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider { width:200px; background:#ddd; overflow:hidden; }
.slider a {color:#000; text-decoration:none; padding:2px 5px; cursor:pointer; background:#ccc; }
.slider a span {display:none;}
.slider a:hover, .slider a:focus { background:#bbb; }
.slider a.left { float:left; }
.slider a.left:hover span, .slider a.left:focus span {display:inline;}
.slider a.right { float:right; }
.slider a.right:hover span, .slider a.right:focus span {display:inline;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pMFmN/

Edit: forgot :focus on anchors

Comment: Brill this worked great thanks - and was able to style the spans accordingly. Thanks a lot. This was the end result http://jsfiddle.net/VzNFw/3/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <span>&lt;</span>
    <span>&gt;</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider { width:200px; background:#ddd; overflow:auto; }
#slider span { padding:2px 5px; cursor:pointer; background:#ccc; }
#slider span:hover { background:#bbb; }
#slider span:first-child { float:left; }
#slider span:first-child:hover::after { content:' PREV'; }
#slider span:last-child { float:right; }
#slider span:last-child:hover::before { content:'NEXT '; }
```

Note: the CSS 3 magic does not work in IE.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/eUCMu/1/